# How can I infer the precision of my sample?

Tags: sampling, inference, survey, survey-sampling

Let's say I have a survey about the quality of my product. But only 30% of my customers answered. If, for instance, the average rate for my product quality is 7, what can I infer from the real rate? I mean, if 100% of my customers rated the product, would the rate be 10, 0 or actually 7?
Is there any way of doing this sort of inference?

I checked some other questions, such as [what can I infer if my data follows power law?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269259/what-can-i-infer-if-my-data-follows-power-law), [Given a set of sub-graphs, how to infer the underlying graph?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24306/given-a-set-of-sub-graphs-how-to-infer-the-underlying-graph) and [Non-response rate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22053/non-response-rate). And even though the first and last one are somehow related, I don't think, or I'm not sure, I can relate the answer to my problem.